# Is it incorrect to say a JS module bundler (eg. Webpack) is compiling?

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, compilation

I know a lot of people use the word "compile" quite loosely and interchangeably but I was hoping someone could explain to me like I'm 5 if it's technically incorrect to call a JS module bundler (eg. Webpack) a compiler or a build tool? I often hear things like "you have to compile your JS in order to update your bundle".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely a build tool, and one which *can* be automated. One of the main use cases is to bundle various javascript sources into one or several bundle(s) of javascript, which is generally referred to as 'transpiling'. Transpiling basically means the output is the same language as the input, ie javascript in javascript out. Compiling is generally the act of turning source code into machine language, or IL. Webpack can of course also bundle other things, which is why on their own webpage they refer to it as a bundler.

In a colloquial sense, people often mean 'compile' to be the same as 'build', in the sense that you run your build tool.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack it is a build tool.

Maybe you heard some like "some node package could not compiled for your OS" [like 
 node-sass module](https://github.com/sass/node-sass). This module compliled from source code